# How do I refer to labels in a document from a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, theorems, thesis

I have a thesis class document with about 200 definitions, theorems and lemmas along with a beamer presentation.  While I’m presenting, my audience will be referring to the document.  How can I have beamer use the same numbering as the document in my presentation?

If I do nothing, beamer assigns new numbers to all of the definitions, theorems, and lemmas, which will be confusing.  And because there’s so many items, manually numbering them isn’t an option.

Comment: `\setcounter{theorem}{yournumber}` before the theorems does not work, where `yournumber` is the the theorem number decreased by one?

Comment: I precisely want an automatic numbering, the manually method isn't what I want; I have about 200 definitions, theorems and lemmas! and I down't want to bring numbers from the thesis and put them them manually.

Comment: it may be possible to do something with the label information recorded in the `.aux` file{s} from the main thesis run.  you'll have to preserve the `\newlabel` lines; put them into a file `thesis-labels.tex` and input that file to the beamer run.  you'll have to figure out yourself how to format the output, and you need to make sure the number of arguments to `\newlabel` agrees with what beamer expects; the number of arguments differs if `hyperref` is or is not used, and there may also be other conditions under which that number differs.

Answer (score 6):

You could directly refer to the number of the theorem in your thesis using the `xr` package.

Let's say your thesis looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\label{mytheo}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

Refering: \ref{mytheo}
\end{document}
```

Then you can use the labels with in your presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{document2}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage{refcount}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
test \ref{mytheo}


\setcounterref{theorem}{mytheo}
\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}
\begin{theorem}
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]